# Bash `if` statement versus conditional execution logic

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic

This works, as it should

```
$ bash -cx 'echo $BASH_VERSION; set -euo pipefail; if true; then (echo good reaction, bad result >&2; exit 1); else echo bad reaction; fi'
+ echo '5.2.21(2)-release'
5.2.21(2)-release
+ set -euo pipefail
+ true
+ echo good reaction, bad result
good reaction, bad result
+ exit 1
```

But a similar snippet using conditionals instead doesn’t. I understand why it doesn’t (although I’m not sure why the errfail setting doesn’t stop execution), but would like to know if there’s a way to make conditional execution work like an `if` statement

```
$ bash -cx 'echo $BASH_VERSION; set -euo pipefail; true && ( (echo good reaction, bad result >&2; exit 1); ) || { echo bad reaction; }'
+ echo '5.2.21(2)-release'
5.2.21(2)-release
+ set -euo pipefail
+ true
+ echo good reaction, bad result
good reaction, bad result
+ exit 1
+ echo bad reaction
bad reaction
```

Comment: The failed command (actually subshell) is in a conditional expression, so `-e` won't consider its failure exit-worthy (see [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)). As for making a conditional expression work like `if`: don't even try, it's a nightmarish mess. If you need `if`, just use `if`; that's what it's for.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - thanks for the reference to the BashFAQ, and for the confirmation that `if` is a better construct for complex (i.e., where the `then` part of the conditional may in _any_ case fail) interactions!

Comment: @markp-fuso - sorry - poorly stated. I’m _expecting_ what actually heppens, I’m _asking_ if there’s a way with conditionals (`&&`, `||`) to work the way I _want_ it to work (like an `if` does). I believe it’s a “nightmarish mess”, as @GordonDavisson said.

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail).

Comment: Note that [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will report some unsafe uses of conditionals.  E.g. [SC2015 – Note that `A && B || C` is not if-then-else. C may run when A is true.](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2015).  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: It would help us help you if you didn't write all the code on one line. Why do you need to use `bash -cx` in the [mre] when you could just post a normal script?

Comment: If your commands don't need to modify shell state (e.g. set variables or change options), and you don't mind the overhead of running a subshell, then you could do `( command1 && { command2; exit; } || command3 )`.  `if` is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're going to take the advice to not use [`set -euo pipefail`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail) then I think the question is really just how to use conditionals to mimic:

```
if command1; then command2; else command3; fi
```

so that'd be the following:

```
command1 && { command2; es="$?"; } || { command3; es="$?"; }; (exit "$es")
```

That works because even if `command2` fails, the subsequent `es="$?"` resets the exit status to `success` so that `command3` doesn't get executed and then the `(exit "$es")` at the end spawns a subshell just to get an exit status that's the contents of `es` but, as others have mentioned, it's not worth the effort.

The above assumes you can guarantee that assigning to `es` can't fail (e.g. as it could if `es` was `readonly`)

---

Here's a test script to show the equivalence of the above structure to the `if...then...else` code, including verifying that for each line:

1. The same commands execute.
2. Variables being set at each step are retained in the current shell once the line ends.
3. We have the correct exit status in the current shell at the end of the line.
4. The current shell continues to execute after the line ends.

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# run each line in a subshell just so variables x, y, and z, all start as null for testing

( x=T; if true;  then y=T; true;  else z=T; true;  fi; echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( x=T; if true;  then y=T; true;  else z=F; false; fi; echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( x=T; if true;  then y=F; false; else z=T; true;  fi; echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( x=T; if true;  then y=F; false; else z=F; false; fi; echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( x=F; if false; then y=T; true;  else z=T; true;  fi; echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( x=F; if false; then y=T; true;  else z=F; false; fi; echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( x=F; if false; then y=F; false; else z=T; true;  fi; echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( x=F; if false; then y=F; false; else z=F; false; fi; echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )

printf -- '--------\n'

( { x=T; true;  } && { y=T; true;  es=$?; } || { z=T; true;  es=$?; }; (exit "$es"); echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( { x=T; true;  } && { y=T; true;  es=$?; } || { z=F; false; es=$?; }; (exit "$es"); echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( { x=T; true;  } && { y=F; false; es=$?; } || { z=T; true;  es=$?; }; (exit "$es"); echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( { x=T; true;  } && { y=F; false; es=$?; } || { z=F; false; es=$?; }; (exit "$es"); echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( { x=F; false; } && { y=T; true;  es=$?; } || { z=T; true;  es=$?; }; (exit "$es"); echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( { x=F; false; } && { y=T; true;  es=$?; } || { z=F; false; es=$?; }; (exit "$es"); echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( { x=F; false; } && { y=F; false; es=$?; } || { z=T; true;  es=$?; }; (exit "$es"); echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
( { x=F; false; } && { y=F; false; es=$?; } || { z=F; false; es=$?; }; (exit "$es"); echo "$x?$y:$z -> $?" )
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
T?T: -> 0
T?T: -> 0
T?F: -> 1
T?F: -> 1
F?:T -> 0
F?:F -> 1
F?:T -> 0
F?:F -> 1
--------
T?T: -> 0
T?T: -> 0
T?F: -> 1
T?F: -> 1
F?:T -> 0
F?:F -> 1
F?:T -> 0
F?:F -> 1
```

Comment: I’m not accepting this answer as I think it would be more correct just to `|| true` command2, and because @Gordon Davisson answer in comments is less confusing code.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion as being `{ command2 || true; }` then that would be wrong, because then if `command2` failed the final exit status of the line would be success instead of fail as it would be if you used `if ... then`. You don't have complete, correct code that fully mimics the `if...then` behavior in any comment which is why the code you do have in comments is simpler than the code in my answer.

Comment: @Larry I just added a test script which you can copy/paste/modify to test any other potential solution(s). If you can find a more concise solution that produces the same results  in all cases then please post it as an answer and let me know as I may have missed something and I'd be very interested in seeing it.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the test script. If I understand correctly, you're using the assignment statement `es=$?` to set the return code to zero. I think I'd prefer `true` (especially when the module is compiled and loaded to make true a builtin), but I think this answers the question, so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm primarily using `es=$?` so save the exit status from the previous command to use in `(exit $es)` at the end of the line. That has the side-effect of also setting the current exit status to success but that's a secondary benefit just coincidentally useful in this context.

Comment: You cannot replace `es=$?` with `true`, if that's what you were suggesting, without breaking the logic such that it no longer mimics what the equivalent `if-then-else` does since that would cause the final exit status at the end of the line to be success rather than fail if the command in the `then` leg failed, but you can **add** a call to `true`, i.e. change `es=$?` to `es=$?; true` if you feel there's some value in that (the call to `true` will functionally do nothing though, the exit status will be "success" with or without it).

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something in the trivialness of this question?

```
true && { echo good reaction, bad result >&2 ; exit 1; } || echo bad reaction
```

I'm not sure why you are making big use of ( ), because that forks a subshell, and you don't want to do that unless you need to do that. Use { } to group commands if necessary, although by the time you use { }, you might well have been better off with `if then`

Comment: The parenthetical clause was to mimic the invocation of a command that issues an error message and exits with a non-zero return code. I guess I could have done something like `date -IX` or `w -x`.

Comment: That would not allow any subsequent line of the script to run after `echo good reaction,...` executes as the `exit 1` would exit the running shell. The `exit 1` in the OPs code is in a subshell and so would avoid that problem. Using a subshell to call `(exit value`) is how you set `$?` to some specific value  in the current shell (usually a value that had been saved in a variable from some previous commands exit status)